# Excel formula for deleting rows

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for an Excel formula to automatically delete all even or odds rows.

Example: I want to delete row A2, A4, A6, ... , and A500, so doing it manually is a pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the column with the formula:

`X2 = isEven(row(X2);` Any row is fine

Then:

- Select the range.
- **Sort** by the column X.
- Delete the *true* or *false* accord your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Row1:

```
=ISODD(ROW())
```

copied down to suit. Filter that column and uncheck the rows you wish to retain (eg uncheck FALSE to keep the even numbered rows). Delete all visible or, depending upon your choice, all visible other than Row1.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting rows may not be possible using excel formula, use vba for automating this process; use the following code if you want to delete odd rows then change startatrow to 1 and if even number then leave it at 2. I am assuming you have a column with complete dataset, lets say column A (you can change it accordingly)

```
Sub deleteAlternateRow()  

    Dim startAtRow, rowCounter, lastrow As Long  
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    startAtRow = 2 
    For rowCounter = startAtRow To lastrow step 2 
        Rows(rowCounter).Select  
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp  
    Next  
    End Sub
```